# Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport: Command Confirmation

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to start an Azure SQL database export with the command `Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport`, but the command always asks for confirmation.

After confirmation the process works well.

`Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport` itself doesn't have a `-confirm` or `-force` option.

Where does this come from and how to prevent this?

```
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport 
      -SqlConnectionContext $SqlContext -StorageContext $StorageContext 
      -StorageContainerName $containerName -DatabaseName $dbName 
      -BlobName $BlobName -Verbose -Debug
```

> DEBUG: 09:34:13 - StartAzureSqlDatabaseExport begin processing with ParameterSet 'ByContainerName'.
>
> Confirm
>   Continue with this operation?
>   [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

Comment: remove  -debug at the end of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `-debug` switch.